# Unable to import modules

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I have installed scipy under local path `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy`

however I am having problems with the imports of type

> from scipy import linalg

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scipy2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy import linalg
ImportError: cannot import name linalg
```

I have basic experience with python therefore got no clue how actually these imports works.

Searching around the web I think the following script shows the import paths

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print path
```

Output:

```
/home/fliu/workspace/python
/home/fliu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-19.4-py2.7.egg
/home/fliu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg
/home/fliu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swiglpk-1.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/lib64/python27.zip
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/fliu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

> ls ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy

```
BENTO_BUILD.txt  __config__.pyc   __init__.py      interpolate  linalg      odr                            setup.pyc  special     version.pyc
_build_utils     constants        __init__.pyc     io           linalg.pxd  optimize                       signal     stats       weave
cluster          fftpack          INSTALL.rst.txt  _lib         misc        pip-delete-this-directory.txt  sparse     THANKS.txt
__config__.py    HACKING.rst.txt  integrate        LICENSE.txt  ndimage     setup.py                       spatial    version.py
```

what could be wrong ?

Comment: do you have `scipy.py` in your working dir? It's first dir on your pythonpath, if name would be matched there it won't even look in site-packages.

Comment: ops.. you are right. really dumb mistake.